# Error "left promiscuous mode" al arrancar Docker

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando arrancar una imagen centos via Docker y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
root@RPI02:~# docker run --name CENTOS7 -it centos:centos7 /bin/bash
failed to resize tty, using default size
```

Si miro los logs del sistema, aparece lo siguiente:

```
Dec 27 09:53:08 RPI02 kernel: [  823.632717] docker0: port 1(vethf4e0561) entered disabled state
Dec 27 09:53:08 RPI02 kernel: [  823.632717] docker0: port 1(vethf4e0561) entered disabled state
Dec 27 09:53:08 RPI02 kernel: [  823.659695] eth0: renamed from veth6dfea5b
Dec 27 09:53:08 RPI02 kernel: [  823.688030] docker0: port 1(vethf4e0561) entered blocking state
Dec 27 09:53:08 RPI02 kernel: [  823.688049] docker0: port 1(vethf4e0561) entered forwarding state
Dec 27 09:53:14 RPI02 kernel: [  829.405366] device vethf4e0561 left promiscuous mode
Dec 27 09:53:14 RPI02 kernel: [  829.405390] docker0: port 1(vethf4e0561) entered disabled state
```

Sabeis que puede estar pasando?

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro, pero prueba a añadir "--disable-drop-privileges" en la sentencia. Puede ser tema de permisos

Comment: no... me sale esto: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"--disable-drop-privileges\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: luego de ejecutar `docker run` no puedes hacer nada?

Comment: nada... me sale en el log: Dec 27 21:06:27 RPI02 dhcpcd[444]: vethd2e14db: deleting address fe80::5e60:7f13:9f43:ac3f
Dec 27 21:06:27 RPI02 dhcpcd[444]: vethd2e14db: removing interface